# Change time interval in SKAction.waitForDuration() as game goes on

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

Basically this is one of the actions in a repeating sequence of actions. Each time the action gets called up in the sequence, i want the waiting time to increase, so i added a counter to act as the waiting time number and increment whenever the action gets called up in the sequence. The problem is with this, is that the variable only increments when the sequence starts, but doesn't change at all when the action happens again in the sequence, The waiting time remains constant throughout the game. and i can't figure out how to get it to change when it gets called up

```
var timeInterval = 0
//main method
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    var scale = SKAction.scaleTo(5,duration: 2)
    sprite = spriteSet(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "texture"), color: UIColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100,100))
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([waitAction,scale,waitAction])))
}
//I want the time to increase each time this function is called in the sequence
func waitFunction() -> SKAction {
    timeInterval++
    return SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(timeInterval))
}
```

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what happens when you run this?

Comment: Basically this is one of the actions in a repeating sequence of actions. Each time the action gets called up in the sequence, i want the waiting time to increase, so i added a counter to act as the waiting time number and increment whenever the action gets called up in the sequence. The problem is with this, is that the variable only increments when the sequence starts, but doesn't change at all when the action happens again in the sequence, The waiting time remains constant throughout the game. and i can't figure out how to get it to change when it gets called up.

Comment: Are you saying that it only increments one time?

Comment: repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([waitFunction, play, waitFunction])))      When the sequence first starts, the variable increments right away, but never agian, and it remains constant

Comment: is there a way to increment the time interval for the waitforduration method? if there isn't is there another way to increment the wait time in an skaction or method or something

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code to give you an answer

Comment: just updated the code description ^^

Comment: can you please show us how waitFunction gets called and how waitAction gets created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the recursive way to accomplish what you want (increment duration of wait parameter):

```
class GameScene:SKScene {

    var wait:NSTimeInterval = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        NSLog("Start") //Using NSLog just to print the current time
        recursive()

    }

    func recursive(){

        let recursive = SKAction.sequence([

            SKAction.waitForDuration(++wait),
            //Do your stuff here, eg. run scale, move...
            SKAction.runBlock({[unowned self] in NSLog("Block executed"); self.recursive()})
            ])

        runAction(recursive, withKey: "aKey")
    }
}
```

What you are currently experiencing, is that *wait* action is created, initialized and reused in an action sequence. You have to rebuild an action each time.

Comment: this will end up blowing up the stack eventually,  I would not take this approach

Comment: You know what,  nevermind, I take that back,  the runblock executes on the update loop, so self.recursive should be able to end, not retaining the block

Comment: Will it? Pretty sure they have good tail call optimization, but maybe it will. Did you try it?

Comment: Nvm my comment too I guess :)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You haven't actually tried this, right ? Retain cycle in this example might be created because of the fact that closure expressions capture values from their surrounding context, thus the [unowned self] part which prevents that from happening. Can't see other way to create retain cycle here (if that's what you've meant by "blowing up the stack").

Comment: I was more worried about self.recursive{self.recursive{self.recursive{self.recursive}}}} happening, not the actual block maintaining ownership, but like I said I take it back because the function is allowed to finish since runBlock does not fire until the update phase, allowing the recursive function to finish, thus allowing the block itself to finish