# How to gradually speed up falling nodes over time?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have two dots that fall parallel to each other from the top of my screen that are to be matched with two circles on the bottom that can be rotated with touch. I have them generated like this:

```
  class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


   runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(generateDots),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))
    }
func generateDots() {
         let count = 2
    let index=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
    let dots = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Color\(index+1)")
    dots.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    dots.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    dots.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    for i in 0..<2 {
        dots.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)
        dots.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << index)

    }

    addChild(dots)
    dots.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45)

    dots.position = CGPointMake(150, 400)
    dots.runAction(
        SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -900,
            duration: NSTimeInterval(11.5)))

          }
   }
```

Is there any way to gradually speed up either how fast they're falling or gradually change the `waitForDuration` so that over time it will produce a node every 3 sec, then 2 sec, then 1 sec and so forth?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624292/change-time-interval-in-skaction-waitforduration-as-game-goes-on

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there also a way to speed up the nodes as well?

Comment: Define a variable for the duration parameter of `moveByX` action and decrease that variable in the "recursive" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely doable! You just need to add some variables.

If you want to change how fast they fall then you need to make a variable like

```
Var droptime:NSTimeInterval = 11.5
```

Then in your "dropdot()" method you need to do two things.

1. At the beginning subtract or devide your droptime variable like...

   Droptime -= 1
2. Then at the end when you generate the falling action make it

   Duration: droptime

Instead of what it was before.

If you want to make the generation time be shorter then you need to make a function that you can trigger each time you want to make your action that the scene runs (like you did in the viewdidload) and edit it so that it has variable wait and triggers itself.  Also you will need to self trigger it once in your didMoveToView method.

```
    func controlMethod() {
    waitdur -= 1
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever( SKAction.sequence([
                    SKAction.runBlock(generateDots),
                    SKAction.waitForDuration(waitdur),
SKAction.runBlock(controlMethod)
    ])))
    }
```

Good luck!

So sorry for the formatting! I'm on mobile...  Hopefully someone can fix it.

Comment: Really quick though, what would be the variable for that `waitdur`? Would it be `var waitdur: CGFloat = 0` or something like that?

Comment: Var waitdur:NSTimeInterval = 1.0

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a double that apples frameworks like to use to represent time.