# Swift SpriteKit: How do I change action duration after every repeat in RepeatForever of SKAction?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I am attempting to set the duration of `SKAction.moveBy` to reduce by 1.0 every time it repeats. For some reason when `SKAction.repeatForever` is ran, variables such as duration (or `wallSpeedMultiplier`) do not get changed on the repeat. Does anyone know a work around to this?

I tried putting it in a sequence with an action to change the duration, to move the object, then wait for the movement to be done to repeat.

```
var wallSpeedMultiplier = 10.0

...

let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 200, timePeriod: 15.0, midPoint: road!.position)
road!.run(SKAction.resize(toWidth: 100, duration: 2.0))

let multiplyIt = SKAction.run { [self] in
    wallSpeedMultiplier = wallSpeedMultiplier - 1.0
}
let moveIt = SKAction.moveBy(x: size.width, y: 0, duration: wallSpeedMultiplier)
let waitIt = SKAction.wait(forDuration: wallSpeedMultiplier)

let sequenceIt = SKAction.sequence([moveIt,waitIt, multiplyIt])

road!.run(SKAction.repeatForever(oscillate))
road!.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequenceIt))
```

Tried solution from https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/34633329/3402095

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !gameStarted {
        gameStarted = true
                 
        road!.run(SKAction.resize(toWidth: 100, duration: 2.0))

        recursive()
    }
}

func recursive() {
    let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 200, timePeriod: wallSpeedMultiplier, midPoint: road!.position)
    let multiplyIt = SKAction.run { [self] in
        wallSpeedMultiplier = wallSpeedMultiplier - 5.0
    }
    
    let recursive = SKAction.sequence([oscillate, SKAction.wait(forDuration: wallSpeedMultiplier),multiplyIt])
    road!.run(recursive, withKey: "aKey")
}
```

FIXED:

```
func recursive() {
    let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 200, timePeriod: wallSpeedMultiplier, midPoint: road!.position)
    let multiplyIt = SKAction.run { [self] in
        wallSpeedMultiplier = wallSpeedMultiplier - 5.0
        print(wallSpeedMultiplier)
        print(oscillate)
    }
    
    let recursive = SKAction.sequence([oscillate, multiplyIt, SKAction.run({[unowned self] in NSLog("Block executed"); self.recursive()})])
    road!.run(recursive, withKey: "aKey")
}
```

Comment: Actions, once made, are not changeable later. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34633329/3402095. You have to re-create action.

Comment: If you end up stuck even after reading, let me know, I will make some example for you.

Comment: Thank you @Whirlwind I tried that solution but it just repeats forever without any waiting. I updated code in question on bottom of my implementation

Comment: `func recursive() {
    let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 200, timePeriod: wallSpeedMultiplier, midPoint: road!.position)
    let multiplyIt = SKAction.run { [self] in
        wallSpeedMultiplier = wallSpeedMultiplier - 5.0
        print(wallSpeedMultiplier)
        print(oscillate)
    }
    
    let recursive = SKAction.sequence([oscillate, multiplyIt, SKAction.run({[unowned self] in NSLog("Block executed"); self.recursive()})])
    road!.run(recursive, withKey: "aKey")
}` here is the answer if you want to post because your comment helped a lot! I got it working!

Comment: Nah, it fine. Glad it worked. And yeah, you forgot to call `recursive()` inside itself.. I mean, that is a point of recursive function :) And if you want to stop this action, just find it by key, and remove it.